# Angular UI navbar collapse not working in _Layout.cshtml (asp.net MVC 5)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created an asp.net mvc 5 template project and change the _Layout.cshtml to this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" ng-click="isNavCollapsed = !isNavCollapsed">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">A menu</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" uib-collapse="isNavCollapsed">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.2.0.js"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/controller.js")
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</body>
</html>
```

```js
// controller.js added in scripts folder
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('CollapseDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.isNavCollapsed = true;
});
```

The problem is collapse is not working when I run the app (home/index) in an asp.net project.

What am I missing ?

The navbar does collapse if Im not using asp.net mvc. something is surely wrong in the _Layout.cshtml